# clang llvm very long compliation time on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, llvm, clang

Hi i have been compiling llvm and clang on my cygwin env using CC=gcc-4 and CXX=g++-4 flags as gcc 3.4.x doesnt seems to compile llvm clang at all. But my question is about the age long compilation time. I have been compiling this from 8pm in the evening and right now its 1:35 am. Also the size of my build directory has gone above 8 gigabytes. And still i see

```
llvm[5]: Linking Debug+Asserts executable clang-format
```

Is this normal? Can i somehow make this faster?

Comment: cygwin is often very slow at this stuff.

Comment: RAM size is important. Under Linux, I found a lot of paging when I had 3GB of RAM. I upped it to 8GB it sped up quite a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some stats

Compiler: GCC 4.5.3
Clang, LLVM: 3.2

- A Debug+Assert build took me around 8 hours to build with total build
  size over 11 gigabytes.
- A Release+assert took mere 1 hour with 800 megabytes of build only.

Also for Release build (configure with **--enable-optimized**) i used make with **-j 4**. But i highly doubt the long compilation time was mainly due to debug build as warned by build process itself.

```
Note: Debug build can be 10 times slower than an optimized build
```

Comment: Thanks! That was quite helpful.  Also may want to add the --enable-targets= (in my case, x86_64) switch to avoid building PPC, ARM, etc. (which it seemed to be doing on my build).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because of Cygwin. You should be able to build them with MS Visual Studio, and some have done it with Mingw.

Comment: well if it counts i have done it on cygwin too, rather painfully, with total compile time of some odd 8 hours and build size of 11 gigabytes.  oh and i got this msg at the end of build **Note: Debug build can be 10 times slower than an optimized build** Let me try again with optimized build and get back on this. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is pretty much expected. LLVM / clang are written in C++. So, there are tons of debug information there. Linker is having really hard times trying to merge everything together.

On Linux the usual suggestion is to try gold instead of ld. This usually speeds everything up tenfold.